# Replace pattern each time with a different string (taken from external file)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have an input:

```
a
b TOCHANGE
c
d 
e TOCHANGE
```

where I need to change the patterns "TOCHANGE" using an external file :

```
line1
line2
...
```

so that I get the following output :

```
a
b line1    
c
d
e line2
```

I tried the following command :

```
while read k ; do sed -i "s/TOCHANGE/$k/g" input ; done < externalfile
```

but I got :

```
a
b line1    
c
d
e line1
```

Comment: You may be able to just drop the `/g` from the end of your `sed` command. Then each repetition should change only the first `TOCHANGE` it finds

Comment: @cunninghamp3, dropping the `g` would stop `sed` changing more than one occurrence _per line_, but not on the whole file (there would still be up to one replacement per line of the file)

Comment: does `TOCHANGE` always come as the 2nd column?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - yup. another instance of my mixing up what i can do in `vim` with `sed` Doh!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's{TOCHANGE}{chomp ($repl = <STDIN>); $repl}ge' input <externalfile
```

With `awk`, assuming `TOCHANGE` doesn't occur in `externalfile` (or more generally that replacements don't generate new occurrences of `TOCHANGE` which could also happen for instance on an input that contains `TOTOCHANGE FROMTOCHANGE` and `externalfile` contains `CHANGE` and `WHATEVER`):

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 PAT=TOCHANGE awk '
  {
    while ($0 ~ ENVIRON["PAT"]) {
      getline repl < "externalfile"
      gsub(/[&\\]/, "\\\\&", repl)
      sub(ENVIRON["PAT"], repl)
    }
    print
  }' < input > input.new
```

(`POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` is needed for GNU `awk` where without which it wouldn't work correctly for replacement strings that contain backslash characters).

Note that `$PAT` above is taken as an extended regular expression. You may need to escape ERE operators if you want them to be treated literally (like `PAT='TO\.CHANGE'` to replace `TO.CHANGE` strings).

Comment: or just with `-P` option

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, well using `-P` would make that code non-portable, while using `POSIXLY_CORRECT` would be harmless with other `awk` implementations.

Comment: So many thanks, this awk solution solved the problem !

Comment: Hmm, instead of gsub+sub, one could use `match()` in the while condition, then use string concatenation: `$0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) repl substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with GNU sed as given:

```
sed -e '/TOCHANGE/R file_2' input.txt |
sed -e '/TOCHANGE/N;s/TOCHANGE\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/'
```

In the first pass, **sed** will place a line of file_2 below the TOCHANGE line for all lines in input.txt

In the next pass, the line comprising TOCHANGE will be joined together with the following line and a s/// substitution will get the intended output.

With **Perl** it can be accomplished as:

```
perl -pe 's|TOCHANGE|<STDIN> =~ s/\n//r|e' input.txt < file_2
```

Answer (score 1):

With this awk

```
awk -v old='TOCHANGE' '
NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}
$2==old{$2=a[++i]}
1' changefile infile > outfile
```

Comment: Note: this solution will work in one case only - if `"TOCHANGE"` pattern occurs only at once in each line and it is the second field. But maybe it's enough for solving the OP task.

Answer (score 1):

Couple tricky solutions with the specific `awk` features usage.

#### First variant

If the `"TOCHANGE"` pattern occurs only at once in each row. The usual `awk` will be enough.

```
awk '{
    if(NF == 2) {
        getline OFS < "file_2"
        $1 = $1
    }    
    print
}' FS='TOCHANGE' input.txt
```

#### Second variant

If the `"TOCHANGE"` pattern can occur many times in each row. The `gawk` needed.

```
gawk '{
    RS="\n"
    if(RT)
        getline ORS < "file_2"
    else
        ORS=""

    print

    RS="TOCHANGE"
}' RS='TOCHANGE' input.txt
```

---

#### Testing

**input.txt**

```
a
b TOCHANGE
c
d 
e TOCHANGE
f
g TOCHANGE
```

**file_2**

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

**Output**

```
a
b line1
c
d 
e line2
f
g line3
```